# SQL Server - set column_id as a Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I Have 2 tables:

Table A with the columns:

```
 Table A
 ---------
 ID
 Name
 Address
```

Table B with the columns:

```
 Table B
-------
 ID
 A_ColumnIDs
```

**I want to set to `B.A_ColumnIDs` a foreign key to `A` table's `column_id`s.**

i.e. the valid values for the column `B.A_ColumnIDs` are: `1,2,3` as the `column_id`s of the columns.

I have a script to take the id and the name of the columns:

```sql
    SELECT 
        C.name ColumnName,
        C.column_id ColumnID
    FROM sys.tables T
        INNER JOIN sys.columns C
            ON T.object_id = C.object_id
    WHERE C.object_id = OBJECT_ID('A')
```

The result of this script is:

```
 ColumnName | ColumnID
-----------------------
 ID         |    1
 Name       |    2
 Address    |    3
```

Now I want the `ColumnID` to be the foreign key of `B.A_ColumnIDs`

But I don't know how to set the foreign key to it.

**The story behind the request:**

I need to be able to restrict the values I get in `B.A_ColumnIDs`, by the existing columns in `A`, and if a column is added / removed / renamed in `A`, I want to stay synchronized.

Comment: @SaReGa, requesting you to please share details like 1. Your `Table A` create statement means are`ID, Name and Address` is `primary key`?

Comment: Only ID is a primary key, but why is that matter?

Comment: `Foreign key` can only be created with a reference to a `primary key` or `unique key`

Comment: But I need a reference only for the name of the column. not the column value!

Comment: I think you need to first check https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php It should clarify your doubts regarding `foreign key` and help you with the syntax also.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want to achieve overall there. Having a column name in the data most likely indicates a questionable design. Other than that there might be a path you can go: Create a table, that should store all the column names of `A`. Initially fill it with what `A` currently has. Then create DDL/event triggers, that add or remove column names from that table when columns get added/removed from `A`. Put a unique constraint/index on the column that has `A`'s column names in it and reference that in your foreign key in `B`.

Comment: In table B you could ad a column `A_Id` and then you can make this a foreign key referencing table A column Id

Comment: @GuidoG, Yes that's what I need. How can I set this foreign key?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correct, but I think you want this

```
create table A (
  Id int not null identity,
  Name varchar(100),
  Address varchar(100),
  ...

  constraint PK_AId primary key (Id)
)

create table B (
  Id int not null identity,
  A_Id int not null,
  other columns...,

  constraint PK_BId primary key (Id),
  constraint FK_B_A foreign key (A_Id) references A (Id)
)
```

now you have a relation between both tables, where B can have multiple rows connected to one row in A

Is this what you want ?

Comment: No, You referenced to the column `Id`. I need to reference to the `column_id` of column `id`.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, can you explain with some sample data ?

Comment: Yes, I've added the result of the script to the question

Comment: It is still not clear at all what you want. Please try to explain in more detail or in other words

Comment: show sample data of both tables and describe exact what you want

Comment: "column_id" does not exist in your table. It is meta-data that is maintained by the database engine. You cannot alter or modify the meta-data directly. If you desire a foreign key, you define the constraint using the columns in your tables not column in the system tables.

Comment: @SMor, So what can I do?
I need to be able to restrict the values I get in `B.A_ColumnIDs`, by the existing columns in `A`, and if a column is added / removed / renamed in `A`, I want to stay synchronized.

Comment: now you are talking about something complete different then foreign keys. Please update your question and explain in detail exact what you need. Use sample data to demonstrate what you want. We dont understand what you are asking